# Make one method taking in a lambda to print with different conditions java

Tags: java, lambda

So i have this code:

```
ArrayList<Meeting>[] calendary = new ArrayList[31];
```

```cs
public class Meeting{
    private LocalTime startTime;
    private LocalTime endTime;
    private String describtion;
    private final static LocalTime YEARLY_START_POINT = LocalTime.of(5, 0);
    private String priority;
    private boolean status;
}
```

And the task is to make one method taking in a lambda to print elements from array "calendary", but i dont know how to achieve this.
It suppose to do things like to print meetings from calendary where status==true, or print all elements
where describtion == "sth". And we pass condition in method parametr

Comment: "make one lambda method", judging by the rest of your question, are you sure you're not meaning "make one method taking in a lambda/predicate"? It sounds like you want a method that prints all matching elements, and "matching" is something you can pass in.

Comment: your code is java code and not c#, so please change the tag or change the code

Comment: You can dynamically specify predicates. Refer to "To filter by using a switch statement" section in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/dynamically-specify-predicate-filters-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
ArrayList<Meeting>[] calendarys = new ArrayList[31];
List<Meeting> meet = new ArrayList<>();
List<Meeting> sth = new ArrayList<>();
Arrays.stream(calendarys).map(calendary -> {
    if (calendary.getStatus()) {
        meet.add(calendary); //collect meetings
    } else if (calendary.getDescription().equals("sth") {
        sth.add(calendary); //collect all describtion == "sth"
    }
    return null;
});
```

Comment: Comparing strings with `==`, ugh! `equals`, or `equalsIgnoreCase` are used for that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure about this structure? An array of lists is not nice.

You can achieve it easily with passing multiple `Predicate<Meeting>` into a method that would filter the values for you.

```
private static List<Meeting>[] filtered(List<Meeting>[] list, Predicate<Meeting>... predicates) {

    // No predicates, no filter
    if (predicates == null || predicates.length == 0) {       
        return list;
    }

    // Build one Predicate from others
    Predicate<Meeting> predicate = Arrays.stream(predicates) 
        .reduce(Predicate::and)
        .orElse(p -> true);

    // Filter the meetings and return in the original data structure
    return Arrays.stream(list)
                 .map(meetingList -> meetingList == null ? null : 
                        meetingList.stream()
                            .filter(predicate)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                 .toArray(List[]::new);
}
```

Just remember the code would fail when a `null` would occur at the place an instance of type of `List` should appear. For that reason, use a ternary operator to return a `null` list immediately instead of trying to stream over it which would hit a NPE... or better, assure the proper objects are passed or use a different and more flexible data structure.